# Why does my layout get messed up after clearing FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS flag?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a single Activity application. It displays a `LoginFragment` which makes Status and Navigation bars translucent so that it can display a background image behind it. However, after login this fragment is replaced by another fragment which needs to display the usual solid Status and Navigation bars. So, before `LoginFragment` gets removed it unsets the flags it had set, to make the bars opaque.

The problem that I am facing is that after I login, the fragment with normal Status and Navigation bars has its Action bar displaced down. If I rotate my screen to landscape and then back to portrait to force the recreation of the layout then the Action bar snaps back to correct position.

*When Status bar is translucent. This is perfectly fine.*
[image: When Status bar is translucent. This is perfectly fine.]

*On next screen Action bar is displaced downwards. Also notice that Status bar is black in color, it should have been gray, according to theme.*
[image: On next screen Action bar is displaced downwards.]

*Now if I go back to first screen, the top translucent bar is fine, but the whole content is shifted upwards, leaving a blank white space below.*
[image: Now if I go back to first screen, the top translucent bar is fine, but the whole content is shifted upwards, leaving a blank white space below.]

Code in `LoginFragment` which programmatically makes the bars translucent and also restores them:-

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (hasTransparentStatusBar()) {
        setStatusBarTranslucent();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    if (hasTransparentStatusBar()) {
        setStatusBarOpaque();
    }
    super.onPause();
}

protected boolean hasTransparentStatusBar() {
    return true;
}

protected void setStatusBarTranslucent() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        Window window = getActivity().getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
    }
}

protected void setStatusBarOpaque() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        Window window = getActivity().getWindow();
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
    }
}
```

Layout xml of Activity:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.app.MainActivity" >

    <!-- The main content view -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/divider"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

`LoginFragment`'s layout xml:-

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:padding="@dimen/default_margin"
    android:text="Login using Facebook"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="@drawable/com_facebook_button_background"
    android:id="@+id/authButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Finally the only workaround which fixed this is that I moved `LoginFragment` under another new Activity which displays its fragments in immersive mode. The rest fragments are still served by the original Activity.

Comment: I had a similar problem but with views instead of fragments. For me, `w.getDecorView().requestApplyInsets()` worked after clearing translucent flag.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer from Froyo, I am going to post it!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem before, so if anybody stumbles on this, the correct workaround is to set the **NO_LIMITS** flag :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
}
```

Comment: I have absolutely no idea why, but I confirm that this works (setting FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS instead of FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS makes the status bar translucent and it doesn't leave blank space at the bottom).

Comment: This causes problems with the navigation bar on devices that have UI navigation bars instead of hardware buttons (e.g. Nexus 5X)

Comment: Agreed with yuval, this flag makes the devices soft navigation became transparent, becareful with it

Answer (score 4):

After setting all those flags on the window for the transparent status bar.
Calling `w.getDecorView().requestApplyInsets()` fixes the issue.
Credits to @Froyo in the comments

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem and it seems we should set window flags before [onActivityCreated(Bundle)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)). 
I'm often using static methods to showing my fragments, like this:

```
public class FragmentPlayer extends MediaFragment
{

    public FragmentPlayer()
    {
        // Default public constructor required. 
    }

    public static void show(@NonNull Activity activity, boolean compact)
    {
        boolean isOrientationPortrait = UiHelper.isOrientationPortrait(activity);
        setupWindow(activity.getWindow(), isOrientationPortrait, compact);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        FragmentPlayer newFragment = FragmentPlayer.getInstance(compact);
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_player, newFragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    private static void setupWindow(@NonNull Window window, final boolean isOrientationPortrait,
                                    final boolean compact)
    {
        if (compact)
        {
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
        }
        else
        {
            if (isOrientationPortrait)
            {
                window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
                window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
            }
            else
            {
                window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
                window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

As you can see I moved all [Window](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html) initialization from `onCreateActivity(Bundle)` to static method `setupWindow(Window, boolean, boolean)` and now everything works just fine.

Still don't know why layout actually get's messed up when calling those methods from `onCreateActivity(Bundle)`, but that's the start.

**Edit 1:** oh, and don't forget to also setup your `Window` in `Activity.onCreate(Bundle)` to properly handle screen rotations!

Answer (score -1):

I tried all possibilities to fix this issue and found a clear solution.
First do the things shown in the [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WGFUGCjAGw4)
and add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` in xml.